ESP32 board layouts
When laying out a PC board for a DAQ system using a ESP32-S3-WROOM-1U-N16R2 chip, can I use a double sided board?  I do not have 4 layer capabilities/talents.

According to the ESP32-S3 PCB Design Guidelines, while 4-layer boards are preferred, 2-layer boards are acceptable.
The overall guidance for doing this is to put all traces and components on the top layer and try to make the bottom layer one big ground plane, if possible.
See further details in the guidelines doc.
